# Why was I prevented from debugging Microsoft Outlook?

Tags: debugging, outlook

Well, it's Friday, and I just got an error message in MS-Outlook. Then it presented me an option, to either close the program, or to Debug it. I chose, bravely I thought, to debug it:

I waited a good 2 minutes, then.  it says

Unhandled exception at 0x76eb15de in OUTLOOK.EXE: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Then, In MS Visual Studio,
"No Source Available - no symbols are loaded for any call stack frame" .

How do I figure out what happened to OUtlook? How can I let Microsoft know that I'd like to debug Outlook? thanks

Comment: You can't debug it because you don't have the source code. The best you could hope for is the assembly code which might not be very useful. Of course, that raises the question of *why* is it given as an option...

Comment: Microsoft is rather unlikely to give you Outlook's source code.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: The system's crash dialog has no way of knowing what you have symbols for.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner - What if I want the source code? Or that's top=secret I guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently I am disallowed from seeing MS source code, thus they won't let me "really" debug...